# Calling a function before autocmd event is triggered

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, autocmd, functions

In my vimrc I have a key mapping for switching buffers that also automatically resizes the splits by calling a function:

```
nnoremap <silent> <M-h> <c-w>h:call Splitresize()<CR>
```

I also would like to automatically switch to insert mode when entering a terminal buffer, so I wrote:

```
autocmd BufEnter term:* startinsert
```

The problem is that when use `<M-h>` to change to a terminal buffer, the autocmd is executed before the function call, so that `:call Splitresize()` is printed in my terminal.

Is there a way to ensure that the function is called before the autocmd is executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `<cmd>` pseudo key to call a function without involving command-line mode (`:h <cmd>`)

For example:

```
func! Splitresize()
        echom "Resize!!!"
endfunc

nnoremap <silent> <C-h> <c-w>h<cmd>call Splitresize()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-l> <c-w>l<cmd>call Splitresize()<CR>

augroup test | au!
        autocmd! BufEnter term://* startinsert
augroup END
```

[image]

Comment: Is that two opportunities in one day you've had to use `<cmd>` in an answer? Pretty good for a command I don't recall seeing mentioned before.  :)

Comment: @BLayer, indeed :) Recent vim also has it.

Comment: Oh, awesome! I was just going to comment that I hope they port it there. Looks super handy.